# Folders in Downloads opening in new window in Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10, download

I have a strange bug in explorer.

My Downloads folder is located at E:\Downloads (moved from default location). When I opening folder as Start - Explorer - E: - Downloads there are no any problems.

But when I click Start - Explorer - This PC - Downloads, and then open any subfolder - it opening in new window, and Downloads add to Navigation Pane, screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVg1f.png]

This bug appear only in Downloads folder.

Comment: This appears to be a Win10 bug. I have a variation of it happening, where opening a directory in Explorer sometimes closes and re-opens the window, losing all the navigation history in the process. It is irritating.

Comment: I have founded solution. It's appear after using Photoshop CC quick export function.
Delete key from registry and restart Explorer:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me.  One thing you could try is in the command prompt running as an admin, try entering the command "sfc /scannow" and see if there are any windows file violations.

Comment: Thank you, but violations not found.